# NetBeans 6.8 'Add JAR/folder' folder added, yet package does not exist

Tags: netbeans, classpath

I have following problem with NetBeans 6.8. I add folder with jars through Project Properties -> Libraries -> Compile tab -> Add JAR/folder. In next window I choose folder and select 'copy to libraries folder'. However I still cannot import any packages. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: you may want to add some details about the package that is not found, the folder that you selected and its content.  it will make the question a lot easier to answer correctly.

Answer (score 1):

I have encountered the same problem.  my understanding is that you need to select the jar files themselves, not just the folder that contains them. (you can, of course, select and add all of them in one step).